# How to create a binary variable to indicate if two statements are true?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking to run a loop to create a binary variable that identifies if two statements are true. In this case, I'm looking to identify if the defensive team is also the home team (ie: the stadium is the defensive team's home stadium).

```
Offensive Team       Defensive Team         Stadium                   
Dodgers              Yankees                Yankee Stadium
Red Sox              Dodgers                Dodger Stadium
Cubs                 Astros                 Wrigley Field
Yankees              Dodgers.               Yankee Stadium
```

Thus, I want my final dataframe to look like this.

```
Offensive Team       Defensive Team         Stadium                Defense_Home          
Dodgers              Yankees                Yankee Stadium         1
Red Sox              Dodgers                Dodger Stadium         1
Cubs                 Astros                 Wrigley Field          0
Yankees              Dodgers                Yankee Stadium         0
```

I understand of course that I will have to write out a full list of stadiums and which teams they correspond to--just looking for a template for how to code it in. I also understand that this is a pretty beginner-level question, as I am not that good at writing loops in R--doing the same thing in STATA would be much easier for me. Still learning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use a loop. Use a single `ifelse()` statement, but you need to create a separate data frame linking teams to stadiums. If you want to provide data here, use `dput()`.

Comment: `df$defense_home <- stadiums[df$defensive_team] == df$stadium` where `stadiums` is a named vector like `stadiums <- c(Cubs = 'Wrigley Field', Yankees = 'Yankee Stadium', ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dataframe with team name and it's corresponding home stadium.

```
lookup_data <- data.frame(Team = c('Yankees', 'Dodgers'), 
                          home_stadium = c('YankeeStadium', 'DodgerStadium'))
```

You can then merge this data with original dataframe by Team name and add 1 if `Stadium` and `home_stadium` are same.

```
transform(merge(df, lookup_data, by.x = 'DefensiveTeam', by.y = 'Team', 
    all.x = TRUE), Defense_Home = as.integer(Stadium == home_stadium))
```

You can also do this with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  left_join(lookup_data, by = c('DefensiveTeam' = 'Team')) %>%
   mutate(Defense_Home  = as.integer(Stadium == home_stadium))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you again for your help. I tried the transform command to combine the new dataframe with the existing datafframe. But I seem to be getting somewhat randomly assigned values in the Defense_Home column. I went back and double checked the new dataframe that I created that matches stadium name to Team, and it looks like I defined each stadium correctly, but when I merge that to the original dataframe I'm getting screwy results. Any idea where I may be going wrong?

Comment: What results do you get? Perhaps, add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating the csv above and reading the data in R.

Comment: After re-examining, I realized that the issue was only with one team, whose  stadium name was "National's Park". When I typed out the code for it in my word document, I inadvertently used a different kind of apostrophe within the name, which led to a mismatch between the two stadium columns, and caused Defense_Home to read as 0 for all values for that team. In short, the problem was my own fault, your code worked just fine. Thank you again!